# Ошибка get запроса при обращении через Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Делаю REST приложение, BE на Spring Boot, FE на Nuxt.js, для работы с API использую axios.

При get обращении к http://localhost:8000/api/ через браузер или с помощью Postman я получаю от сервера соответствующий ответ, все работает хорошо, но при обращении через Nuxt у меня вываливается ошибка.

Текст ошибки:

```
{ "config": { "transformRequest": {}, "transformResponse": {}, "timeout": 0, 
"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN", 
"maxContentLength": -1, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, 
*/*" }, "method": "get", "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000/", "url": 
"http://localhost:8000/api/" }, "request": {} }
```

В чём проблема?

Метод из компонента:

```
methods: {
  fetchData() {
    this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/')
      .then(response => {
        this.test.push(response)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
 ],
axios: {
// proxyHeaders: false
 }
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что дело в cross сайтовом запросе, но могу ошибаться. И ещё вариант - попробуйте получить данные через js fetch api, если это проблема axios, то работать будет нормально.

Comment: да, это дело в cross сайтовом запросе, спасибо за правильное направление